# Update the text of textField from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm trying to update one textfield from another class:

I have two classes:

```
  @interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <PostDistanceControllerDelegate>  {
id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

IBOutlet UITextField *currentStatus;
IBOutlet UITextField *currentUpdateDate;
}
@property ...
```

In my FlipsideViewController.m I can use:

```
@implementation FlipsideViewController

//....

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender{
   currentStatus.text=@"TOTO";
}
```

Now I have a second class in which I'm trying to update the text from the first class...

```
@implementation OthersideViewController

-(void)setStatus{
   [FlipsideViewController currentStatus.text=@"TEST"};
}
```

I know I can't re-initialize the controller because it's already initialized. I tried to extern the currentStatus field and it doesn't work. I tried using a getter and a setter as your would do in Java and it the debugger says: unrecognized selector

Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for tips! I finally got it to work. I also found that I can globalize the pointer for an instance so I can call it back later. 

Ie: globalVars.m

FlipsideViewController *flipper;

From my first class (which imports the globalVars)
extern FlipsideViewController *flipper;
flipper = controller; //supposing that controller was initiated.

Then you can use flipper as a reference.

[[flipper currentStatus] setText:@"TEST"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set a property of a member by sending a message to the class and that's why it doesn't work.  You'll need to have a reference to the instance of FlipViewSideController and call such as:

```
-(void)setStatus{
   [FlipsideViewControllerInstance currentStatus.text=@"TEST"};
}
```

So either you pass the FlipViewController instance to your setStatus method as a parameter

```
-(void)setStatusOfViewControllerLabel:(FlipViewController *) FlipsideViewControllerInstance {
   [FlipsideViewControllerInstance currentStatus.text=@"TEST"};
}
```

or you keep a reference to it in your OthersideViewController object.

Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have declared your property and then synthesized it, and you have a     "FlipsideViewController *flipside" variable, then you can use

```
[flipside currentStatus].text = @"TEST";
```

or

```
[[flipside currentStatus] setText:@"TEST"];
```